# Confusing result of "GetElementType" on arrays and generic lists

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, reflection, generic-list

**Generic list:**

```
var elementType1 = typeof (List<A>).GetElementType();
```

**Array:**

```
var elementType = typeof (A[]).GetElementType();
```

Why do I only get the element type of an array?
How could I get the element type of a generic list? (remark: the generic list is boxed)

Comment: Could you clarify what your remark "the generic list is boxed" means?

Comment: boxed means that you only have this list as an object.

Comment: That's not boxing. Boxing only applies to value-types.

Comment: @Ani what is this then called?

Comment: `List<T>` is a reference-type; a value (in general : expression) of such a type is a *reference* to an object. I'm guessing you just have a variable of a *less-specific* type (e.g. `object`) that refers to a `List<SomeT>` instance. That's just about assignment-compatibility, not boxing. It's a representation-preserving conversion; no boxing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**`GetElementType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) only gets the element-type for array, pointer and reference types.

> When overridden in a derived class,
>   returns the Type of the object
>   encompassed or referred to by the
>   current array, pointer or reference
>   type

The reflection API doesn't "know" that `List<T>` is a generic *container* and that the type-argument of one of its constructed types is representative of the type of the elements it contains.

Use the [**`GetGenericArguments`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method instead to get the type-arguments of the constructed type:

```
var elementType1 = typeof(List<A>).GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Comment: is there also a good approach to find out if I have a generic list or an array? I could proof for null and then use your solution, but maybe there is something better.

Comment: Array = `type.IsArray`.  ListT = `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)` (You will also need to verify that the type is a constructed generic type).

Answer (score 5):

```
var elementType1 = typeof(List<A>).GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
var elementType = typeof(int[]).GetElementType();
```